# Executing runtime javascript in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to execute the script tag which I will be receiving from the API. The API response will contain HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I want to execute the response script tag in my Vue 3 application.

As per the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/security.html#injecting-javascript), the Vue does not allow JavaScript injection and there is no clear documentation that says it's not possible to inject.

So is it possible or not?

You can have a look at the attached screenshots for reference.

[API Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WsLv.png)

[HTML Markup which is visible in the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwPMu.png)

[HTML Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeAty.png)

Comment: Please, don't post images for code. If Vue doesn't add script tags in normal way, you need to do this yourself. You can check vue-plugin-load-script (not specific to Vue). But the problem is that the snippet that you receive wasn't written to run in Vue app. It will very likely be buggy and cause memory leaks.

Comment: Have you tried `v-html` ?